# laravel join table if data exists

Tags: join, laravel, eloquent

What is the best way to join table A with table B, if table B has data and if not just give me data from table A? because if I do it in this way, and there are no photos in table B I don't get data from that row from table A.

```
$data =  Category::join('photos', 'categories.cover_id', '=', 'photos.id')
    ->get(['categories.id',
           'categories.position', 
           'categories.visible', 
           'categories.created_at', 
           'categories.updated_at', 
           'categories.title', 
           'photos.filename']);
    return $data;
```

my idea is just to make another request to get all data from table A where categories.cover_id is 0 (without join)

my tables are just

```
table A (categories)
-------------------------------
| id | title | cover_id | ... |
-------------------------------
| 1  | lorem |    1     | ... |
-------------------------------
| 2  | ipsum |    12    | ... |
-------------------------------
| 3  | dolor |    0     | ... |
-------------------------------

table B (Photos, there is no data for dolor, because i created dolor recently in table A)
---------------------------------
| id | title |  filename  | ... |
---------------------------------
| 1  | lorem |  lorem.jpg | ... |
---------------------------------
| .. | ..... |  ...jpg    | ... |
---------------------------------
| 12 | ipsum |  ipsum.jpg | ... |
---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be fine by just using a [`leftJoin()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins). A normal ("inner join") will only return results from both tables. But a **left join** returns all results from the *left* table (in this case `categories`) and everything that exists from the other table.

```
$data =  Category::leftJoin('photos', 'categories.cover_id', '=', 'photos.id')
->get(['categories.id',
       'categories.position', 
       'categories.visible', 
       'categories.created_at', 
       'categories.updated_at', 
       'categories.title', 
       'photos.filename']);
```

Or you could...

### Use the power of Eloquent

You only need to define the relationship (I assume you already have a `Photo` model) and this gets a lot easier

```
class Category extends Eloquent {
    public function photos(){
        return $this->hasMany('Photo', 'cover_id');
    }
}
```

And then...

```
$data = Category::with('photos')->get();
```

And you will have the photos model nested inside the category models. Accessible like this:

```
foreach($data as $category){
    foreach($category->photos as $photo){
        echo $photo->filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you. that sounds great and i have learned something new with eloquent;)

Comment: In your first solution, what if we need to apply a where condition on 'photos' table?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it this way:

```
// Just assuming a few variables for better understanding
$allCategories = Category::all();

foreach ($allCategories as $category) {
    $photo = Photo::find($category->cover_id);
    if ($photo) { // $photo!=null or isset($photo) - you can use anything
        // photo is found do the additional processing
    }
    //proceed with your normal processing
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment. But is this a good approach? Because now i have to make everytime an extra call to table B(Photos) when cover_id is set in table A (categories). This seems to me a little slow...

Comment: This solution would cause the N+1 problem discussed in http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading You would get one query to load all categories, and one for every category to retrieve any photos.

Comment: Yea, that's right..!..My mistake in this case. It won't be optimal..!